# How to get value of adjacent cell in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table

I am trying to build a simple connected-tables multi-sheet in Google Sheets, for tracking expenses.

My tables are as follows, and connected by [data-validation](https://zapier.com/blog/data-validation-google-sheets/).

In the column name, I state where I want the data to come from. Either the source is "typed", "by dropdown", or "by link".

`expenses`

| what? (by dropdown from "what?" table) | category (by link from `what?` table) | price (by typing) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pizza | restaurants **(should be auto fed when selecting "pizza"under "what")** | 4 |
| train | transportation **(should be auto fed when selecting "train"under "what")** | 6 |

`what?`

| name (by typing) | category (by drop down from column "name" in `catrgories`) |
| --- | --- |
| pizza | restaurants |
| train | transportation |

`catrgories`

| name (by typing) |
| --- |
| restaurants |
| transportation |

I have everything working except for the "category" column in the `expenses` table.
I want to select a value by drop-down for the "what?" column in the `expenses` table, and want the value under the "category" column to be fed automatically, from the corresponding cell to that selected, from the "category" column in the `what?` table.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got something working, but not sure it is the best practice

The formula for cells under the "price" column in `expenses` is

`=INDEX(whats!B:B, MATCH(B2, whats!A:A), 1)`

which means

1. Find the index of the value specified in the relevant cell (B2 in this example)
2. Access the **second** column (B) in the `whats` table, and obtain the value.

This works, but would love to hear if there's a better way.